# Client Side Object model code goes in onFailure function

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I am using the client side object model to approve multiple items from the form library. I need to access the values of some of the columns of the form library. The following is my code:

```
      var context;
       var web;
       var itemCount;
       var count = 0 ;
       SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Approving item(s)...');
       approveItems();
       function approveItems ()
       {     
         alert('testttt');
         context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         web = context.get_web();
         context.load(web);
         var currentLibId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
         var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentLibId);          

          // Get all the items in the list
          employees = currentLib.getItems(); 
          alert('employees:'+employees);
          // Load the web in the context and retrieve only selected columns to improve performance 
          context.load(this.employees, 'Include(ID,FirstName)');              
          alert('after load.');
          context.executeQueryAsync(get_Employees_onSuccess,get_Employees_onFailure);               
          alert('after...');
       }  

        function get_Employees_onSuccess() {
           // Get the collection
           alert('inside success..');
           var employeeCollection = this.employees.getEnumerator();          
           alert('employeeCollection' +employeeCollection);
           while (employeeCollection.moveNext()) {
              var employee = employeeCollection.get_current();
              alert('id: ' +employee.get_item('ID'));
              alert('FirstName: ' + employee.get_item('FirstName'));              
           } 
        }
        function get_Employees_onFailure() {
           alert('An error occurred while fetching data. Please contact your system administrator.');
        }
```

When I deploy the solution and test, the alert of the onFailure is displayed. I am not able to figure out the reason why the code in onSuccess is not executing.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your app with error handling like this:

```
function onFailure(sender, args) {
    ULS.enable = true;
    ULSOnError(args.get_message(), document.location.href, 0);
    //if debugging
    alert(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Where can I see the logs? In the ULS Log viewer?

Answer (score 0):

`getItems` takes `SP.CamlQuery` object as parameter. If you need all items use ID > 0. Forexample:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>
```

[SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx)